# Android SQLiteOpenHelper is not working

Tags: java, android

The onCreate void of my `SQLiteOpenHelper` is not called even when get a database with `"database = helper.getWritableDatabase();"`. I read lots of posts on this page here but I didn't find any solution that worked for me.

**SQLiteOpenHelper**:

```
package eu.michael1011.currencies.sql;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String database_name = "currencies.db";

  public static final String col1 = "id";
  public static final String col2 = "value";

  public Helper(Context context) {
    super(context, database_name, null, 1);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d("database", "started");

    db.execSQL("create table EUR ("+col1+" TEXT, "+col2+" TEXT)");

    Log.d("database", "finished");
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists EUR");

    onCreate(db);
  }
}
```

I call it in my main activity like this:

```
helper = new Helper(getBaseContext());
database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: The `onCreate(...)` method is only called once (when the database is created) and not every time you're opening it via `#getWritableDatabase()`.

Comment: just follow this tutorial and you will make your app as you want http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: Are you getting any particular error?

Comment: But it's not working. I uninstalled the app. This was in the onCreate method: "db.execSQL("create table test ("+col1+" TEXT, "+col2+" TEXT)");". When I want to execute this: "        ContentValues val = new ContentValues();

        val.put(Helper.col1, "col");
        val.put(Helper.col2, "col2");

        Main.database.insert("test", null, val);
" 
I get this error: Error inserting value=col2 id=col
                                                                           android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table

Comment: @Michael can you show the logcat.

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/raw/VwbL1ZGU